# Ao abrir solution, os folders com os projetos não aparecem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Criei uma solution, baseado no video do Eduardo Pires. Salvei e fui fazer outra coisa. Bem, ao reabrir a solution, os folders com os projetos não aparecem, ficando apenas a Solution indicando (0 project). Como eu faço para mostrar os meus folders?

Lembrando que os folders estão lá, abrindo pelo windows explorer estão todos la´, os folders e os projetos.

Comment: Aconteceu isso comigo. Verifiquei que o sdk que defini no global.json não estava instalado. Instalei e ao criar os projetos dentro da mesma solution agora aparecem normalmente.

Answer (score 3):

Já tentou ir na opção mostrar todos os arquivos na solution?

[image: imagem]

(Está destacado em vermelho o ícone)

E depois disso basta selecionar as pastas do projeto e dar botão direito e selecionar "`Include in Project`"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então, o que estou achando estranho é que no meu Solution Explorer não tenho essa opção. Foi a primeira coisa que tentei fazer. Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Tenta então dar botão direito na `solution -> add -> Existing Project`  e seleciona o `.csproj `que deve estar dentro de alguma pasta da `solution`

Comment: Mas e os folders? Quando eu faço isso, só adiciono os class library, mas preciso adicionar todos os meus folders e não sei porque isso aconteceu. Gostaria de entender o que realmente aconteceu.

Comment: Quando você adicionou o .csproj apareceu outro item a baixo abaixo da solution certo?? Clicando no projeto, não aparece a opção de mostrar todos os arquivos?? Provavelmente seu .sln ou .csproj está corrompido.